# jQuery - Append each input value to one

Tags: jquery, html, onkeypress

I have some text box, for example 4 inputs, I want to append each value to one certain text box with comma on KeyUp function beside default value but problem is it will overwrite value with previous value.

want something like this:

> 01115468852, 234324234, 423423113345, 43341889955

```js
var curval = $('#PhoneTextbox').val();

$('.tag').each(function() {
  $(this).keyup(function() {
    var tags = $(this).val();
    $('#PhoneTextbox').attr('value', curval + " , " + tags);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="PhoneTextbox" value="01115468852" type="text" />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<input class="tag" value="" type="text" />
<input class="tag" value="" type="text" />
<input class="tag" value="" type="text" />
<input class="tag" value="" type="text" />
```

Comment: you forget to update the curval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.tag').each(function () {
    $(this).keyup(function () {
        var tags = $(this).val();
        var curval = $('#PhoneTextbox').val();
        $('#PhoneTextbox').attr('value', curval + " , " + tags);
    });
});
```

This way you add it at the end of the last added value

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like

```js
var curval = $('#PhoneTextbox').val();

var $tags = $('.tag').keyup(function() {
  var tags = $tags.map(function() {
    return this.value || undefined
  }).get();
  tags.unshift(curval)

  $('#PhoneTextbox').val(tags);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="PhoneTextbox" value="01115468852" type="text" />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<input class="tag" value="" type="text" />
<input class="tag" value="" type="text" />
<input class="tag" value="" type="text" />
<input class="tag" value="" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 2):

use `.change()` instead of `.keyup()`

```js
   $('.tag').each(function () {
$(this).change(function () {
    var tags = $(this).val();
    var curval = $('#PhoneTextbox').val();
    $('#PhoneTextbox').attr('value', curval + " , " + tags);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="PhoneTextbox" value="01115468852" type="text"/>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<input class="tag" value="" type="text"/>
<input class="tag" value="" type="text"/>
<input class="tag" value="" type="text"/>
<input class="tag" value="" type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this javascript code

```
var p = $("#PhoneTextbox").val();
$(function(){
    $('.tag').keyup(function(){
        var t = [];
        t.push(p);
        $('.tag').each(function(i,e){
            if($(e).val().length > 0){
                t.push($(e).val());
            }
        });
        $("#PhoneTextbox").val(t.join());
    });
});
```